# Iptables rules suddenly not working

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, debian, iptables

I'm trying to set up a webserver using an [Odroid U3](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=g138745696275); as OS I have Debian 7.4. The issue came when trying to load the iptables rules with iptables-persistent. I'm using the same file with rules I've been using for some time, but for some reason now it refuses to work (I have another server with Odroid U2 and Debian 7 and it works fine).

iptables-restore gives a failure message on the line with the COMMIT.

I've isolated the problem to the ssh brute force prevention part. When trying to add those rules manually I get "iptables: No chain/target/match by that name."
Here are the rules:

`:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [8:1088]
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 67,80,465 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 67,80,465 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --sports 22,67,80,465 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 67,80,465 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT`

-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH --rsource
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m recent --rcheck --seconds 30 --hitcount 4 --rttl --name SSH --rsource -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m recent --rcheck --seconds 30 --hitcount 3 --rttl --name SSH --rsource -j LOG --log-prefix "SSH brute force "
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m recent --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 3 --rttl --name SSH --rsource -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

-A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out!

On my other machines I had Debian **Wheezy** and the armfh version of the iptables package was **1.4.14**

The current system is Debian **Jessie** where the version is **1.4.21** (latest)

Somewhere along the line the --set (and from the looks of it the whole "recent" part) has been dropped.

Will need another way to prevent brute forcing...

Comment: [`fail2ban`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/fail2ban) may be of help

Comment: ...and what happens if you do `find /lib/modules/ -type f -name '*recent*' -print` ? Does it find a module named `xt_recent.ko`? I'd say the stock Jessie kernel for `armhf` [does have this module](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=xt_recent.ko&mode=path&suite=testing&arch=armhf).